# How do I configure Db2 on Cloud as source in Apache Zeppelin?

Tags: jdbc, db2, ibm-cloud, apache-zeppelin, dashdb

I am trying to use my Db2 on Cloud instance hosted on IBM Cloud with an Apache Zeppelin notebook. I tried to follow the [JDBC setup instructions](https://zeppelin.apache.org/docs/latest/interpreter/jdbc.html), but it resulted in "class not found" error.

I used `com.ibm.db2:jcc:11.5.8.0` as Maven artifact in the dependency settings and `com.ibm.db2` as default driver.

I run this cell:

```
%Db2
select count(*) from syscat.tables
```

which results in this error message:

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.ibm.db2     at
> java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)    at
> java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)     at
> sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:352)     at
> java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)     at
> java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)   at
> java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)   at
> org.apache.zeppelin.jdbc.JDBCInterpreter.createConnectionPool(JDBCInterpreter.java:501)
> at
> org.apache.zeppelin.jdbc.JDBCInterpreter.getConnectionFromPool(JDBCInterpreter.java:512)
> at
> org.apache.zeppelin.jdbc.JDBCInterpreter.getConnection(JDBCInterpreter.java:539)
> at
> org.apache.zeppelin.jdbc.JDBCInterpreter.executeSql(JDBCInterpreter.java:747)
> at
> org.apache.zeppelin.jdbc.JDBCInterpreter.internalInterpret(JDBCInterpreter.java:935)
> at
> org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.AbstractInterpreter.interpret(AbstractInterpreter.java:55)
> at
> org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.LazyOpenInterpreter.interpret(LazyOpenInterpreter.java:110)
> at
> org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.RemoteInterpreterServer$InterpretJob.jobRun(RemoteInterpreterServer.java:849)
> at
> org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.RemoteInterpreterServer$InterpretJob.jobRun(RemoteInterpreterServer.java:741)
> at org.apache.zeppelin.scheduler.Job.run(Job.java:172)  at
> org.apache.zeppelin.scheduler.AbstractScheduler.runJob(AbstractScheduler.java:132)
> at
> org.apache.zeppelin.scheduler.ParallelScheduler.lambda$runJobInScheduler$0(ParallelScheduler.java:46)
> at
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
> at
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Any tips?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the setting for the default driver. It needs to be `com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver`. I found the solution in the setup instructions for [Big SQL with Apache Zeppelin](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2-big-sql/5.0.3?topic=notebooks-configuring-db2-big-sql-interpreter-apache-zeppelin).

[image: accessin Db2 on Cloud from Apache Zeppelin]